# Problema con switch en Java

Tags: java, java-util-scanner

Tengo un menú con switch con 3 opciones que hace lo siguiente:

1. Captura de Datos
2. Consulta de datos
3. Finalizar

En la opción 1 se solicita al usuario todos los datos necesarios. En la opción 2 quiero mostrar estos datos que fueron guardados.

La pregunta es, cómo puedo hacer esto?. Cómo puedo mostrar los datos que fueron guardados en las variables en la opción 1?.

Código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Menu_1 extends Variables {
   public static void main(String[]args) {
  int opcion;
    do{
        opcion=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,

                "   ELIJA LA OPCION QUE NECESITA UTILIZAR  \n"+

                "1.- Captura de datos \n"+

                "2.- Consulta de datos \n"+

                "3.- Finalizar \n"+

                "INGRESE UNA OPCION(1-3)","MENU PRINCUPAL",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)); 
       switch(opcion){
        case 1: 
   int identificacion;  
    short edad;
    long telefono; 
    int sueldo;
    String direccion; 
    float estatura; 
    double deuda; 
    boolean datos;
    char genero; 
    String nombre;  
    String estudios;
    Short familiares; 
       Scanner teclado= new Scanner (System.in);
       System.out.print("Diguite la direccion: ");
       direccion= teclado.nextLine();  

       System.out.print("Diguite la identificacion: ");
       identificacion= teclado.nextInt();  

       System.out.print("Diguite el nombre: ");
       teclado.nextLine(); 
       nombre= teclado.nextLine(); 

       System.out.print("Diguite la edad: ");
       edad= teclado.nextShort();  

       System.out.print("Diguite el telefono: ");
       telefono= teclado.nextLong();  

       System.out.print("Diguite el sueldo: ");
       sueldo= teclado.nextInt(); 

       System.out.print("Diguite la estatura: ");
       estatura= teclado.nextFloat(); 

       System.out.print("Diguite la deuda: ");
       deuda= teclado.nextDouble(); 

       System.out.print("Diguite los estudios: ");
       teclado.nextLine();
       estudios= teclado.nextLine();  

       System.out.print("Diguite la cantidad de familiares: ");
       familiares= teclado.nextShort(); 

       System.out.print("digite su genero (Masculino o femenino):");
       genero= teclado.next().charAt(0);break;
            case 2: 
          //aqui va la opcion 2 mostrar contenido que fue capturado en la opcion 1, aquí el problema o de que otra manera hacer el menu funcional//

            case 3: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"QUE TENGA BUEN DIA");System.exit(0);break;  
                default:JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ELIJA UNA OPCION VALIDA \n", "ERROR DE OPCION",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    } }while(opcion !=3);
    }    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He entendido tu pregunta sobre tu ejercicio, aunque me ha costado lograrlo por tu pobre explicación del problema.

1. Las variables debes moverlas al comienzo de todo tu programa para que puedan ser accedidas desde cualquier parte del switch.
2. He cambiado tus variables de tipo `short`, `Long` a tipo `int` ya que este último es el más fácil para trabajar. De igual manera he cambiado `float` a `double`.

Código arreglado:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Menu_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Variables
        // Podrán ser accedidas desde cualquier parte del switch
        // Nota: se inicializan las variables
        int identificacion = 0;
        int edad = 0; // He cambiado de short a int
        int telefono = 0; // He cambiado de Long a int
        int sueldo = 0;
        String direccion = null;
        double estatura = 0; // He cambiado de float a double
        double deuda = 0;
        char genero = 0;
        String nombre = null;
        String estudios = null;
        int familiares = 0; // He cambiado de short a int
        int opcion;

        do {
            opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,

                    "   ELIJA LA OPCION QUE NECESITA UTILIZAR  \n" +

                            "1.- Captura de datos \n" +

                            "2.- Consulta de datos \n" +

                            "3.- Finalizar \n" +

                            "INGRESE UNA OPCION(1-3)",
                    "MENU PRINCUPAL", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
            switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Diguite la direccion: ");
                direccion = teclado.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Diguite la identificacion: ");
                identificacion = teclado.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Diguite el nombre: ");
                teclado.nextLine();
                nombre = teclado.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Diguite la edad: ");
                edad = teclado.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Diguite el telefono: ");
                telefono = teclado.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Diguite el sueldo: ");
                sueldo = teclado.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Diguite la estatura: ");
                estatura = teclado.nextDouble();

                System.out.print("Diguite la deuda: ");
                deuda = teclado.nextDouble();

                System.out.print("Diguite los estudios: ");
                teclado.nextLine();
                estudios = teclado.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Diguite la cantidad de familiares: ");
                familiares = teclado.nextInt();

                System.out.print("digite su genero (Masculino o femenino):");
                genero = teclado.next().charAt(0);

                // Cerrar el Scanner
                teclado.close();
                break;
            case 2:
                // Masculino
                if (genero == 'm' || genero == 'M') {
                    System.out.println("\nSeñor " + nombre + ",\ncon identificación No: " + identificacion + ",\nsu información extraída de la base de datos es la siguiente:");
                    System.out.println("Tiene " + edad + " años de edad,\nvive en la " + direccion + ",\nsu teléfono es " + telefono + ",\nmide " + estatura + " metros de estatura"
                            + ",\nsu sueldo es de " + sueldo + ", \nsu deuda es de " + deuda + ".\nUsted es " + estudios + " y tiene " + familiares + " familiares.");
                } else { // Femenino
                    System.out.println("\nSeñora " + nombre + ",\ncon identificación No: " + identificacion + ",\nsu información extraída de la base de datos es la siguiente:");
                    System.out.println("Tiene " + edad + " años de edad,\nvive en la " + direccion + ",\nsu teléfono es " + telefono + ",\nmide " + estatura + " metros de estatura"
                            + ",\nsu sueldo es de " + sueldo + ", \nsu deuda es de " + deuda + ".\nUsted es " + estudios + " y tiene " + familiares + " familiares.");
                }
       break;

            case 3:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "QUE TENGA BUEN DIA");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ELIJA UNA OPCION VALIDA \n", "ERROR DE OPCION",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        } while (opcion != 3);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias eres un duro al adicional Robert le hice una modificacion en el case 2 que me piden el trabajo

Comment: @JuanAndresMolano Estamos para ayudar. Si mi respuesta fue de ayuda, no olvides seleccionarla como Respuesta Elegida. Saludos amigo!.

Comment: Ahora la repuesta debe quedar en filas :(

Comment: @JuanAndresMolano He editado mi respuesta con el código actualizado con los cambios que has sugerido para la opción 2 del switch y he agregado un screenshot de cómo es la apariencia. Si quieres cambiar algo, creo que puedes lograrlo fácilmente jugando con los `\n`. Saludos.